# Control Panel Login Timeout issues

Tags: control-panel, sessions, cookies

I'm on EE 2.7 and clients are complaining of short logout times.

> I’m forced to re-log into EE within 20-30 minutes of non-usage even though you’ve set the timeout to 8.3 hours.

My current settings are

```
$config['admin_session_type'] = "s";
$config['cp_session_ttl'] = 30000; // Keep admins logged in for one business day
```

Any thoughts on other settings to check/change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the [**Control Panel Session Type**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html) to "Cookies only".

Control Panel Location: Admin ‣ Security and Privacy ‣ Security and Sessions

> Only cookies are used to track the admin user. When this setting is
>   used a “remember me” checkbox will appear next to the Control Panel
>   login page, enabling users to stay permanently logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use addon [Stay Up Forever](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stay-up-forever) for this purpose.